# Gradient of a function defined by a linear program

Tags: derivatives, optimization, linear-programming

Let

$$f(a) := \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{ c^Tx : a^Tx \leq b \right\}$$

where $a, c, \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. How can I calculate $\nabla_a f(a)$?

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality let $b = 0$ and $c^T c = 1$.

Say $x = \mu c - v$ with $c^T v = 0$. Then, $c^T x = \mu$. 
Thus, $c^T x$ is bounded from below, if $\mu$ is bounded from below.

1. Let $a = \lambda c + u$ with $c^T u = 0$, that is $\lambda = a^T c$.
2. If $\lambda \ge 0$, then we have
   $$ a^T (\mu c) = \lambda \mu \le 0 $$
   for every $\mu < 0$. Thus, $\mu$ is unbound from below.
3. Assume $\lambda < 0$. Then, we have
   $$ a^T x = \mu a^T c - a^T v = \lambda \mu -  u^T v \le 0$$
   if and only if
   $$ \mu \ge \frac{u^T v}{\lambda}. $$
   Thus, $\mu$ is bounded from below if and only if $u = 0$. In that case, we have $f(a) = 0$.

I leave you to compute the (directional) derivative.